# Tight Baire and Borel measures.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

A Baire measure on a completely regular topological space $(X,\tau)$ is tight if,

$$\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is a compact} Z\text{-set}, K\subseteq A\}$$

A Borel measure on a completely regular topological space $(X,\tau)$ is tight if,

$$\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is compact}, K\subseteq A\}$$

It is then stated that both Borel and Baire tight measures are closed regular.

Where closed regular means that,

$$\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is a } Z\text{-set}, K\subseteq A\}
= \inf\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is a } U\text{-set}, A\subseteq K\}$$

I don't understand why this is the case. So any insight would be much appreciated!

A $Z$-set is a set of the form $\{x\in X | f(x) = 0\}$ for some $f\in C_b(X)$

A $U$-set is the complement of a Z-set.

$\underline{\text{To note}}$: I know that any Baire measurable $\mu$ is closed regular (irrespective of being tight actually). But it certainly does not seem obvious to me why every tight Borel measure is too. And so it seems strange to mention that every tight Baire measure is closed regular, when it is true that this holds without the condition of tightness.

So I'm most interested to hear a similar result that guarantees tightness for Borel measures, as the more I think about it, the less I believe the statement questioned above.